# What method to be used to retrieve data from SQLite in android?

Tags: android, sqlite

Hello Everyone I am new bee in ANDROID so am getting problem in retrieving data from SQLite ,can anyone HELP me to know what method to be used to do so. Thanks

Comment: New bee! That's a great way to put it!

Answer (score 1):

The best database example for Android that I found and used is available on [devx.com](http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/40842/1954)

After going through that tutorial you will get some better idea. Steps to retrieve data are as follows:

1. open database connection using the open method in the example.
2. execute the query using db.query method. that will return a cursor to the returned records and then iterate the cursor to get through the returned records.

Hope it helps.